# Feature importance for particular classes

Tags: dataset

Suppose I have a dataset labeled with two classes such as healthy and unhealthy and I applied feature selection (feature importance) on the dataset.

How can I know if the features are important to a particular class (to healthy or unhealthy)?

Comment: In general feature importance in binary classification modeling helps is a measure of how much the feature help separating the two classes(not related to one class but to their difference). Please share how you preformed the feature selection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are talking about feature importance for decision tree algorithms here - you cannot really say. It only tells you how often a feature is used to split both classes apart.

If you would like more insight into how your model makes decisions you could look into [SHAP](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) and [LIME](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime). Both are methods that approximate your model and then try to explain it. You can check out these two libraries in Python.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers .
I perfmoed features secletion as in link below.
https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-machine-learning-python/

Comment: @lona, glad you found a solution. If you want to be helpful you can always write what you did as an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: Ok Simon ,Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you going.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv("https://rodeo-tutorials.s3.amazonaws.com/data/credit-data-trainingset.csv")
df.head()

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

features = np.array(['revolving_utilization_of_unsecured_lines',
                     'age', 'number_of_time30-59_days_past_due_not_worse',
                     'debt_ratio', 'monthly_income','number_of_open_credit_lines_and_loans', 
                     'number_of_times90_days_late', 'number_real_estate_loans_or_lines',
                     'number_of_time60-89_days_past_due_not_worse', 'number_of_dependents'])
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(df[features], df['serious_dlqin2yrs'])

# from the calculated importances, order them from most to least important
# and make a barplot so we can visualize what is/isn't important
importances = clf.feature_importances_
sorted_idx = np.argsort(importances)


padding = np.arange(len(features)) + 0.5
plt.barh(padding, importances[sorted_idx], align='center')
plt.yticks(padding, features[sorted_idx])
plt.xlabel("Relative Importance")
plt.title("Variable Importance")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi ASH, unfortunately, this does not answer the question of how important different predictors are for different target variables. As pointed out by @Simon Larsson, regular decision tree-based feature importance estimates do not address this.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that.